# Using d3.js to parse float csv file

Tags: d3.js

I currently have this code

```
    d3.csv("month.csv", function(data) {'
    var w = 600;  
    var h = 300;
    var barPadding = 1;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
         d.count = parseFloat(d.count);
         d.value = +d.value;`
     });
    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
                  .rangeRound([0,w])`
                  .paddingInner(0.05);`
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()`
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data.count)])
                  .rangeRound([0,h]);
    function barChart(){
     var svg = d3.select("#bar1")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
    })
```

But after I run it, it says

> unexpected NaN parsing y attribute

I did a `console.log(data.count)` and it says `undefined`

> month.csv
>   
>    month | count
>   
>       1 | 1128
>   
>      2 | 1327
>   
>   3 | 1573
>   
>   4 | 1264
>   
>   5 | 1143
>   
>   6 | 1483
>   
>   7 | 1190
>   
>   8 | 1338
>   
>   9 | 1707
>   
>   10 | 2310
>   
>   11 | 2657
>   
>   12 | 1505
>
> edit

If I do a `console.log(d.count)` within `data.foreach(function(d)` I get the value I need.

Comment: it's probably because you headers columns "month" and "count" which are strings are still included. Would be good to have a sample of the csv file here in order to check it.

Comment: First, that doesn't seem to be a CSV. Second, look at it, whatever that is: there is no `value` column.

Comment: @PierreCapo I copied and paste the csv file through excel, the '|' symbol is the table for excel. Is there a way to upload my csv file?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado refer to above comment.

Comment: @KhooWingHang Ok, assuming that the CSV is valid, where is `value`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is passing data.count to the d3.max function. Since data is an array of objects, data.count attempts to access a count property of the array.

Instead, you have to provide a function as a second argument to the d3.max function, which will access the count property of each element of the data array being passed as the first argument, like this:

```
d3.max(data, d => d.count);
```

or using the old function format:

```
d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; });
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation ( https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv   ):

To use a different delimiter, such as “|” for pipe-separated values, use d3.dsvFormat: https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsvFormat